# PHP - getimagesize Function

Tags: php, getimagesize

Does [getimagesize](https://www.php.net/function.getimagesize) use an extra HTTP request or can it find out the size remotely?

NOTE: The image is external

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will always be at least one HTTP request; otherwise how will it know what you're looking for?

If you're asking whether or not it'll download the file - yes, it will. There's no HTTP header that specifies image dimensions, so it doesn't know until the file is downloaded.

Comment: There is no HTTP request if `getimagesize()` is used on a local file.

Comment: Seriously? His question explicitly states "remotely". He's not looking for a local file request here.

Answer (score 3):

It can fetch it remotely or locally:

> This parameter [filename] specifies the file you wish to retrieve information about. It can reference a local file or (configuration permitting) a remote file using one of the supported streams.

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/function.getimagesize).

Comment: But would it be like using file_get_contents with the image?

Comment: @Ben, check out my answer; it's answering your question, not just throwing the manual back at you.